# Adding a URL to a Photoswipe image caption

Tags: photoswipe

How does one add a url to a Photoswipe image caption?
Everything that I have tried stops Photoswipe from working as it should.
I want to add a link to the photographers website.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML in the item's title attribute works just fine.

```
var $title = '<span><a href="https://domain.tld">Go to domain.tld</a></span>';
var item = {
            src   : ...,
            w     : ...,
            h     : ...,
            title : $title
           };
```